# Grails url mapping exclude dbconsole

Tags: grails

I have a single page web application, grails url mapping contains

> "/**"(view: "/index")

as well as few routes that start with /api/*
The problem happens when I'm trying to access /dbconsole that comes with a plugin. This would still be served through the first mapping. I tried to exclude dbconsole like this

> "/$ember?"(view: "/index", constraints {ember(notEqual: 'dbconsole')})

But it always throws an exception.

Comment: what exception? provide all relevant url-mappings

Comment: Why not just keep dbconsole disabled (or manually disable it via `grails.dbconsole.enabled` if we're talking about the development environment)?

Comment: what if i need dbconsole? @Gregor

Comment: I was assuming you need it disabled since you talked about excluding.. I'll provide a proper answer, then.

Comment: Hmm actually the first thing you can do is add a colon after `constraints`: `constraints: {ember(notEqual: 'dbconsole')}`, the error you're getting is due to bad syntax.

Comment: well I need /dbconsole to serve dbconsole and /** to serve everything else @Gregor

Answer (score 1):

You can define an exclude in the URL mappings:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static excludes = ["/dbconsole*"]
    static mappings = {
        //your app's usual URL mappings
    }
}
```

Since dbconsole is not served through the usual URL resolution process you will still be able to access it.

Comment: I don't see this on the documentation. Can you point me to it?